# Where the key from get_post_meta() is defined?

Tags: php, wordpress, key

I have this line of code:

```
<?php $page_skills = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_ttrust_page_skills_value", true);  ?>
```

And I would like to know where is the "_ttrust_page_skills_value" defined usually so I can handle this case differently?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the key while creating a custom field:

- Using web interface:

  [image]
- Using [`add_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_meta):

  ```
  <?php add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique); ?>
  ```

Consider reading more about [Custom Fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).